# Role resorce not getting updated for the custom module

Tags: module, magento-enterprise

When I tried to add resource to a role, its not getting saved. The checkbox seems to uncheck after saving the role. The resource which I am giving is a custom module. I saw a thread with the same issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196723/magento-custom-module-admin-permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196723/magento-custom-module-admin-permissions.)

But it doesnt help me. I followed the same way but still the issue exist.

I am writting config.xml as follows.

```
<acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Magestore_Bannerslider>
                            <title>Bannerslider Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Magestore_Bannerslider>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <bannerslider translate="title" module="bannerslider"> 
                                            <title>Banner Slider Settings</title>
                                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                                        </bannerslider>
                                    </children>                         
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
```

Please help me.....

Comment: may be you can logout and login to check the roles? Magento doesn't load changes in the roles immediately.

Comment: I tried, but my problem is not solved. I cleared cache and done index management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank guys for the help I sorted it out.The problem was with the config.xml. The changes I made is given below:

```
<admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <bannerslider translate="title" module="bannerslider"> 
                                        <title>Banner Slider Settings</title>
                                        <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                                    </bannerslider>
                                </children>                         
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                    <bannerslider>
                        <title>Bannerslider Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <items translate="title">
                                <title>Manage Banners</title>
                            </items>
                        </children>
                    </bannerslider>
                </children>
            </admin>
```